# TensorFlow Lite - Custom model getting replaced by example model

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite, multiclass-classification

I am learning TensorFlow lite by building a binary Image Classification App for Android. I trained my tflite model by following the official model maker tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification), where I got my `model.tflite` and `label.txt` file saved in the google colab directory. As per the TensorFlow lite tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/image_classification/overview), I added model.tflite and label.txt (containing the labels of my classes) in assets folder on the reference android app. And changed the label filename in code and TensorFlow Lite file name in code of the reference android app.

However, while running the reference app in Android studio, I am still seeing the default model provided by TensorFlow using the default classes for classification, and not the model I trained and classes of classification I created.

Comment: do you remove the original model from the asset folder? so there is only your model in? if yes you probably made a mistake during the training...

Comment: Yes i also tried it by deleting other models in the assets folder keeping only my trained model in the assets folder, but after the build is completed in the android studio, the default model files are downloaded back in the assets folder. Also while using the trained model file in the google colab, the model is showing correct predictions and working correctly

Comment: ah, yes. there is a auto download of the provided tf models. try to comment out in build.gradle (app) the line "apply from:'download.gradle'" I don't know if that's gonna cause any problems.. it's been a while since I used the example app. the other option is to give your model a unique name. search in the app files for the original model name and replace it with your model.

Comment: so i did comment the "apply from:'download.gradle'" and also changed the model name to my unique name removed all other models in the assets file. this time the build was successful and the app got downloaded in my device. but now i am not able to see the my labels and on opening the app, the camera lens works and no results gets displayed.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: please follow this link to access the complete zipped folder of my android project. wherein i have added my model (guns_model.tflite) and label file (guns_labels.txt) in src/main/assets folder and changed the model and label file name in src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/ClassifierFloatMobileNet.java file https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MIsI7TGSKyPJzOYWCUuIOsIzciYn2CU/view?usp=sharing                                                                      Thanks

Comment: do you use a float mobilenet? and do you also selected it in the settings in the bottom sheet? where do you test it, real device or emulator?

Comment: yes i am using the float mobilenet. in which settings in the bottom? i am using my real device. Samsung A50 4GB RAM

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions listed here? https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android

Answer (score 0):

go to download_model.gradle each time the app is built, the gradle download the cefault model replace it with your model link (upload your model to google drive and put the link in the gradle)